# How do I show x and y labels to a live graph in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, axis

I am trying to implement a live graph, however, my x and y axis are not showing up.  Ive tried placing it in multiple areas of the code, however, none of those methods were successful.

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import matplotlib.animation as animation
 from matplotlib import style



 style.use('fivethirtyeight')

 fig = plt.figure()
 plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
 plt.ylabel('Temperature (F)')
 plt.title("Your drink's current temperature")
 plt.xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=10)
 plt.ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=10)

 ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

 def animate(i):
     plt.xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=10)
     plt.ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=10)

     graph_data = open('plot.txt', 'r').read()
     lines = graph_data.split('\n')
     xs = []
     ys = []
     for line in lines:
       if len(line) > 1:
         x, y = line.split(',')
         xs.append(x)
         ys.append(y)
     ax1.clear()
     ax1.plot(xs,ys)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```

Here is the data file that I am reading from (plot.txt):

```
 0,27.00
 1,68.85
 2,69.30
 3,69.30
 4,69.30
 5,69.75
 6,70.20
 7,69.75
 8,69.75
 9,69.30
 10,69.75
 11,69.75
 12,69.75
 13,69.75
 14,70.20
 15,69.75
 16,69.75
 17,69.75
 18,69.75
 19,68.85
 20,69.75
 21,69.75
 22,69.75
 23,69.30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `clear` in your animation function.  You want to just update an existing artist (and let the animation code take care of re-drawing it as needed)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as manimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature (F)')
ax.set_title("Your drink's current temperature")

xs = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 512)
ys = np.sin(xs)

ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)

ln, = ax.plot([], [], lw=3)


def init(*args, **kwargs):
    ln.set_data([], [])
    return ln,


def animate(i):
    ln.set_data(xs[:i], ys[:i])
    return ln,

ani = manimation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                               frames=512, blit=True,
                               init_func=init)
plt.show()
```

if you need to read in from another data source (ex, your file) just read it and then set the data on your line.